# wrong include paths in eclipse after updating ndk

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I have updated android ndk from android-ndk-r9c to android-ndk-r9d but eclipse still uses the 9c include paths as a default and theres no way to delete them. I don't want to add them by hand I just want them to be included by default just like they did with r9c. How can i update eclipse to use the newest ndk-r9d paths?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eUNE.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I surely am too late, but I had the same problem. I solved following these steps:

- open the Eclipse workspace in a File Browser;
- go into `.metadata/.plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk/`;
- there should be a file called `<your-project>.pathInfo`;
- edit the content of that file to match the new NDK path;
- Restart Eclipse.

or maybe you could delete it, delete Native Support from the project and then re-add it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you. Although I have now migrated to android studio, this might come in handy for someone else who is still using eclipse ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the path via configuration? Haven't tested it, but it should work just fine.

`Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> set path to the NDK`

Comment: of course I edited the ndk path to point to the newest ndk folder location but that doesn't update my projects default include paths